# Problema al hacer deploy en Microsoft Azure

Tags: javascript, html, css, azure, deployment

Hice una aplicación web, utilizo `NPM` y varios paquetes de allí, después de hacer `build` de mi aplicación y subir mis archivos finales(solo el `html`, `css` y `js`) a `Azure`, me suelta el siguiente error al cargar la página, no sé que pueda ser, creo que es un error de referencia pero no lo puedo ubicar.

[image: Error Azure]

mi código de la aplicación está aquí [Repositorio GitHub](https://github.com/josevenezuelapadron/TVify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya solucione el problema, era que estaba pasando un parametro a una funcion y luego dentro de la funcion trataba de usar ese parametro pero con otro nombre

[image: Solución error]

La linea comentada contiene el error